# How do I use cin to get a string instead of hard-coding it?

Tags: c++, c++11

As a homework exercise we were asked to use strchr to count the amount of times a single letter appears in a string of text. It needs to count upper or lower cases as equal. It was suggested we use some sort of bit operations.
I managed to get a working program.

But i would like to make the program more interactive by allowing me to use a cin to input the string instead of typing the string directly into the source code (Which was asked by the exercise).
Is it possible to do this? Or is it not possible in the way i wrote this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    const char *C = "This is a necesarry test, needed for testing.";
    char target = 'A';
    const char *result = C;
    const char *result2;
    int count = 0;
    int j[26] ={0};
//================================================================================================================================================
    for(int i = 0; i <= 51; i++){
        if (i == 26){
            target = target + 6;
        }
        result2 = strchr(result, target);

        while(result2 != NULL){
            if (result2 != NULL){
                result2 = strchr(result2+1, target);

                if (i <= 25){
                    j[i] = j[i] +1;
                }
                if(i > 25){
                    j[i-26] = j[i-26] +1;
                }
                cout << target << "\t";
            }


    }

    cout << target << endl;
    target++;

    }

    char top = 'a';
    for(int o = 0; o<= 25; o++){
        cout << "________________________________\n";
        cout << "|\t" << top << "\t|\t" << j[o] << "\t|" << endl;
        top++;
    }
    cout << "________________________________\n";

   }
```

Comment: Take a look at [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use getline() to get a string of characters from the console. Using getline you can also consider the spaces in the user input.

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);
```

Now to use this with the strchr functionn you simply have to convert this into a C Type string which can be done as follows :

```
input.c_str
```

This returns  a C type string so you can put this as an arguement to the function,

You will need

```
#include <string>
```